# Detecting available List operations

Tags: java, collections

I'm writing some code which needs to take a generic `java.util.List` from another source and adapt to the available functions; eg. does it support `add()`, `set()`, etc.

I'm currently just calling the functions on the list and creating a set of available operations, but I'm wondering if there's a better way than `try`-`catch`.

Current code:

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JListPanel<T> extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 832057842976869638L;

    private static enum JLPFlag {
        ADD, REMOVE, SET;
    }

    private List<T> list;
    private Set<JLPFlag> flags = EnumSet.allOf(JLPFlag.class);

    public JListPanel(List<T> backinglist) {
        list = backinglist;
        setFlags();
    }

    private void setFlags() {
        // store the last state
        List<T> prev = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        boolean empty = list.isEmpty();
        try {
            if (!empty) {
                list.add(list.get(0));
            } else {
                // hope that list allows null
                list.add(null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            flags.remove(JLPFlag.ADD);
        }
        try {
            list.set(0, list.get(0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            flags.remove(JLPFlag.SET);
        }
        try {
            list.remove(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            flags.remove(JLPFlag.REMOVE);
        }
        if (flags.contains(JLPFlag.REMOVE))
            list.removeAll(list);
        if (flags.contains(JLPFlag.ADD))
            list.addAll(prev);
    }
}
```

Edit: This is supposed to be a JPanel that contains a list that can be modified by a program and this should reflect those changes on the list display. It's not complete yet, but the ultimate goal is to have a list that can be modified by the user or programmer. It will have some buttons that will be disabled if the list doesn't support the operations, so it might not have `add` or `remove` but it might have `set`.

I've compiled most of the suggestions into this new function: http://pastebin.com/JPWXdFfi

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish. Could you provide a few example `List`s and what the expected behaviour should be?

Comment: I think this is one of the bad design decisions in the java library. As far as I know there is no other way to check, an 'optional' operation is supported by an actual implementation of the List interface than just calling it and checking for the Exception. :-(

Comment: @200 The Java lists are all under the Collections API, and the expected behavior is that any lists which do not support certain functions have the functions disabled in a GUI The flags control that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of attempting to detect this beforehand, consider providing feedback when adding or removing an element fails due to `UnsupportedOperationException`, and then disable related actions in your user interface.  Or use any domain or prior knowledge available to predict whether these operations will be available.

But to answer your question:

Unfortunately, no, there is no fail-safe way to find out what operations a collection implementation supports.  Checking beforehand and catching `UnsupportedOperationException` is a possible but unreliable approach, and it comes with concerns and pitfalls.

That said, let's check what the java.util.Collection API documentation says about this (notes are mine):

> The "destructive" methods contained in this interface, that is, the methods that modify the collection on which they operate, are (1) specified to throw UnsupportedOperationException if this collection does not support the operation. If this is the case, these methods may, but are not required to, throw an UnsupportedOperationException (2) if the invocation would have no effect on the collection. For example, invoking the addAll(Collection) method on an unmodifiable collection may, but is not required to, throw the exception if the collection to be added is empty.

The wording is a bit unfortunate, but it boils down to:

1. **Unsupported operations should throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.**  Catch `UnsupportedOperationException` rather than `Exception`.  Implementations can throw exceptions for reasons that may be out of your hands (like concurrent modification).
2. **Idempotent operations may not throw.**  Implementations may choose not to throw UnsupportedOperationException if they can determine that the invocation is a no-op, such as with `list.set(0, list.get(0))`, or `clear()` on an empty list.

Another potential issue is that lists that support only add or remove, but not both, will be in a modified state after testing:

```
    List<T> prev = new ArrayList<T>(list); // Collections.unmodifiableList(list) is a view, not a copy!
    // list = [A, B]
    try {
        if (!empty) {
            list.add(list.get(0));
            // [A, B, A]
        } else {
            list.add(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flags.remove(JLPFlag.ADD);
    }
    try {
        list.set(0, list.get(0));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flags.remove(JLPFlag.SET);
    }
    try {
        list.remove(0);
        // Add supported: [B, A] 
        // Add not supported: [B]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flags.remove(JLPFlag.REMOVE);
    }
    if (flags.contains(JLPFlag.REMOVE))
        list.removeAll(list);
    if (flags.contains(JLPFlag.ADD))
        list.addAll(prev);
    // Remove but not Add: []
    // Add but not Remove: [A, B, A, A, B]
    // Both or neither: [A, B]
```

Comment: That last part I did think about, but I wasn't sure how to proceed, so I might have to just store a new list internally and have programs pull the list from it.

Answer (score 4):

**After edit original question:**

I understand what you are trying to do, and very nice if you can do that.
That's why I'm trying to think together with you for an solution.
The only thing is that I seems not capable enough to reach to an solution.
That's why I'm still posting mine thoughts.

We have some problems(with solutions) that prevents us to check it at creation of the class :

1. We init with a list, and after constructing the "wrapper" it must be the same list.
2. The original list may support one or more methods, add may be supported and an addAll or remove maybe not,
3. [Adding/removing a null can be supported or not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29). So if we want to test add we need a instance of T.
4. We can make the wrapper abstract and create an `abstract T getInstance ();` where we give a real instance of `T` or we disallow a wrapper with an empty `List`.
   This solves issue 3 but still not issue 2 when only add is supported we can't remove our T from the list. (reversed is not a problem cause it shall return `false` if `T` isn't in the list)
5. Maybe we could use the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) `clone()` what gives a shallow copy but that is in this case no problem as the copy is used to test the methods.
   Still a problem if it throws the `CloneNotSupportedException`.
6. We can at construction check if the `CloneNotSupportedException` is thrown and do the test at runtime => buttons are disabled when user press the button once or buttons are always disabled when cloning isn't possible.

### Other bad solution :

Create an enum with all known implementations of List.
Check for instanceOf of the class and get the flags from the enum.

**Why possible bad :**

`ArrayList` implements everything.
When I create a subclass of `ArrayList` and throw at the `add` an `UnsupportedOperationException` your check for `ArrayList` is good and set the flags for an `ArrayList`.
Still the `add` operation shall not work.

Comment: Wells flags are removed in the `catch` clause for unsupported operations, maybe `initFlags()` sound a little better then? The question is still unclear what is being practically achieved here though...

Comment: I think I know it, he add all the flags in the `Set<JPLFlag> flags` and remove what isn't possible so at the hand of available flags he knows if the list can do an operation or not.

Comment: The method name was wrong as it originally did set flags. I will change it. However, I'd like the list to be the same one as the provided list so that I can change it and the program will have those changes reflected. (This is for a library I'm writing).

Comment: So you want a list that is always editable or a wrapper that will not throw an exception when you do an add operation that is not supported?

Comment: Hmm, I think I'll add some more text to the OP to explain this better.

Comment: Most implementations also have Serializable, could try that.

Answer (score 2):

The first time I read your code I was like.... *"Wait, what?"*

Now I start to understand what you are doing here, but I have some comments:

First of all, to answer your specific question: You don't have another option for this than to use try-catch.

I would not use a private field for the flags, but rather change the method signature to return a `Set<JLPFlag>`, then create this set at the beginning of the method:

```
Set<JLPFlag> flags = EnumSet.allOf(JLPFlag.class);
```

---

I don't like what you are doing here:

```
if (!empty) {
    list.add(list.get(0));
} else {
    // hope that list allows null
    list.add(null);
}
```

It might be better to provide a `T testElement` to the method, in case `null` isn't supported and the list is empty.

---

I have bad experience with making an operation on a list that uses the list, like this:

```
list.removeAll(list);
```

I would change that to:

```
list.removeAll(new ArrayList<T>(list));
```

Or... you could just use `list.clear();`

---

Your JLPFlag enum can have a method for doing the test logic: (If you like this or not is up to you)

```
private static enum JLPFlag {
    ADD, REMOVE, SET;
    public <T> boolean supported(List<T> list) {
         try {
             switch (this) {
                 case ADD:
                     list.add(something);
                     return true;
                 case REMOVE:
                     list.remove(0);
                     return true;
                 case SET:
                     list.set(0, something);
                     return true;
             }
         }
         catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) { return false; }
    }
}
```

---

To restore the list correctly afterwards, I would do this:

```
List<T> prev = new ArrayList<T>(list);
// perform operations...
list.clear();
list.addAll(prev);
```

However, if either `ADD` or `REMOVE` fails, you're screwed and won't be able to restore the list.

Using `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)` is a bad idea IMO as that [reads through](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) to the `list` object. So if you clear your list, your unmodifiableList will be empty.

---

In the end, I think JvR's suggestion is best:

> Instead of attempting to detect this beforehand, consider providing feedback when adding or removing an element fails due to UnsupportedOperationException, and then disable related actions in your user interface. Or use any domain or prior knowledge available to predict whether these operations will be available.